# RxJava Single to Completable to Single - how to pass the result of the first Single to the second Single

Tags: android, rx-java2

In the following method, how do I pass the result of the first Single to the second Single?

As it's written now, when it returns, `somethingId` is empty. If I change the value in the returned `Single.just(somethingId)` to something other than the empty string it will return that value.

What's interesting is that if I breakpoint into the method it stops on line 7 before it goes to line 5 and 6.

The documentation for the `andThen` on line 7 says:

> Returns a Single which will subscribe to this Completable and once that is completed then
>        will subscribe to the {@code next} SingleSource.

Why does it seem to be executing in that order and/or is there a better way to do this?

```
1 override fun downloadSomething(): Single<String> {
2    var somethingId = ""
3    return remoteDataSource.downloadSomething() // this is a Single
4        .flatMapCompletable { something ->
5            somethingId = something.id
6            saveSomething(something) // this is a Completable
7        }.andThen(Single.just(somethingId))
8 }
```

The only thing I can think to do at this point is return a Single for the `saveSomething()` method on line 6 (which works). However I'm then changing the signature of that method just so I can use it in this particular method which doesn't feel right. Surely there's a way to get this to work without doing that?

Comment: Should `saveSomething` must be completable?  If not, you can write `remoteDataSource.downloadSomething().doOnComplete { saveSomething(it)}.map(it.id)`

Comment: yes because the calling function must wait for this to complete before it continues (it will try to get the downloaded thing locally using the id).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve the same result without changing `saveSomething` method signature, if you avoid the `flatMapCompletable` operation altogether:

```
1 override fun downloadSomething(): Single<String> {
2    return remoteDataSource.downloadSomething() // this is a Single
3        .flatMap { something ->        
4            saveSomething(something).andThen(Single.just(something.id))
5        }
6 }
```

Or:

```
1 override fun downloadSomething(): Single<String> {
2    return remoteDataSource.downloadSomething() // this is a Single
3        .flatMap { something ->        
4           saveSomething(something).toSingleDefault(something.id)
5        }
6 }
```

The problem you are having at the moment is that `Single.just(somethingId)` is executed as part of the RxJava pipeline creation and as such, it happens before downloadSomething has finished, and therefore the value of `somethingId` is still an empty string.

Comment: wow thanks for that! great answer. I'm still learning ways of composing RxJava and you've given me more ideas and explained what went wrong.

Comment: Glad I could help!